# Is there a way to make sure CoreML does not return the same result twice?

Tags: swift, machine-learning, coreml

So basically I'm working with a prediction model in CoreML and I would need it to make sure it does not return the same result twice until it returned all results over the course of time. Is this even possible? Any help is appreciated, thanks!